# Why is the accusative used in “Einen Augenblick!”?

Tags: phrase, grammatical-case, accusative

When someone says “Einen Augenblick!”, like the English “Just a moment!”, why is the accusative used and not the nominative case?

Answer (score 12):

In English, “Just a moment!” implies a verb like “wait” or “give (me)”.

The same is true in German, “Einen Augenblick!” is just a shorter form of “Warten Sie einen Augenblick!”, “Geben Sie mir einen Augenblick!” or some variant of that sentence, and these require the accusative (“einen Augenblick” is the direct object).

Comment: 1. The name of this type of simplification is *ellipsis*. 2. German has a bunch of different types of objects, but a *"direct object"* are not among them. German has *dative objects, genitive objects, accusative objects, nominative objects* and *prepositional objects*, but neither *direct* nor *indirect* objects. Open any German grammar book that is used to teach students in Germany, Austria or Switzerland, and try to find the term »direktes Objekt«. You will fail, regardless of which book you choose.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast It is used frequently enough to have made it into Wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objekt_(Grammatik)#Die_Begriffe_%E2%80%9Edirektes%E2%80%9C_und_%E2%80%9Eindirektes_Objekt%E2%80%9C). I used it because it is easy to understand for learners whose first language does not have cases. Btw, some people even advocate that I should not only delete the direct / indirect object from my grammar vocabulary, but also dat. obj, gen. obj. and prepos. obj. (cf. Scholten 2016, 156f.).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Also, my answer wasn’t very clear: I meant to say that from the standpoint of linguistics, my explanation is simplifying what is actually happening in that sentence. I did not mean that in linguistic terms, this phenomenon is called a simplification. I’ll edit that.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, feel free to write a better answer.

Comment: @CarstenS: I already wrote 1,055 answers

Answer (score 0):

Because all noun phrases with a temporal meaning appear in the accusative.

> Könntest du **einen Augenblick** auf das Kind aufpassen?
>   Er geht **jeden Abend** ins Fitnessstudio.
>   Du würdest diese Arbeit **keinen Tag** aushalten.
>   Sie sieht so aus, als würde sie sich **jeden Moment** übergeben.

(The last phrase has the idiomatic meaning of *soon*.)

Comment: *Im Januar* doesn't count as "temporal meaning"?

Comment: @c.p. It's a prepositional phrase.